# Regex expression for numbers with commas and optional .00

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regex pattern for number input. When user enter numbers the comma is automatically separate entered number like 1,424 or 23,232. This is working fine with regex pattern

`/^[0-9.,]*$/`

But the problem is that this pattern allowed dot(.) between numbers. I want to make regex expression like the input can allowed .00 ate the end of numbers not between numbers. But the .00 is also optional.
Allowed number formats are below:

```
123312131256457.00
1233121312564
9,223,372
```

Not allowed number formats are below:

```
34.343455.3434
34353...
```

I spend lost of time on same but does't get any solution. Please share yours ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very, very simple answer would be `/^[0-9,]*(\.00)?$/`. I.e., add an optional `.00` suffix, remove support for `.` literal before the optional part.

---

As commented above you could go for something more fancy: [`^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})*)(\.00)?$`](http://scriptular.com/#%5E(0%7C%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D(%2C%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D)%2A)(%5C.00)%3F%24%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%220%22%2C%2201%22%2C%221%2C1%2C1.00%22%2C%220%2C000.00%22%2C%221%2C000%22%2C%22123312131256457.00%22%2C%221233121312564%22%2C%229%2C223%2C372%22%5D)

This will behave as commented:

```
0 // OK
01 // Not OK, must start with 1-9 if not 0 or 0.00
1,1,1.00 // Not OK, groups must be 3 digits, if used
0,000.00 // Not OK, should be 0.00
1,000 // OK
123312131256457.00 // OK, groups are optional
1233121312564 // OK, decimals (.00) are optional
9,223,372 // OK
```

Comment: It would match something like `123,456789.00`, i.e. it matches numbers which have broken comma patterns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True, it would allow _omitted_ commas.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}((,[0-9]{3})*|([0-9])*)(\.[0]{2})?$/
```

Here is a brief explanation:

```
^              from the start
[0-9]{1,3}     match 1 to 3 numbers
(,[0-9]{3})*   followed by a comma and three numbers, any number of times
([0-9])*       OR just followed any amount of numbers, with NO commas
(\.[0-9]{2})?  followed by an optional decimal point and two zeroes
$              end
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: +1 I was fiddling with something similar. Ended up with: [`^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})*)(\.00)?$`](http://scriptular.com/#%5E(0%7C%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D(%2C%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D)*)(%5C.00)%3F%24%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%220%22%2C%2201%22%2C%221%2C1%2C1.00%22%2C%220%2C000.00%22%2C%221%2C000%22%2C%22123312131256457.00%22%2C%221233121312564%22%2C%229%2C223%2C372%22%5D)

Answer (score 0):

just something like

```
/^[0-9,]*(?:\.0+)?$/
```

but `[0-9,]*` also allows "3,,,"